# Filter keys with specific JSON values in JSON-LD files

Tags: arrays, json, command-line, automation, jq

I have a zip file(GZ) which when unzipped contains JSON in each line. Below is one sample JSON line. I am trying to extract specific fields only to CSV file using `jq`. I want to extract these fields with a condition that the `type` key should have the value `dissertation` only.

```json
{
  "id": "https://openalex.org/W2777209504",
  "doi": "https://doi.org/10.24026/1818-1384.1(42).2013.77470",
  "display_name": "Hyperandrogenism as a factor of reproductive losses",
  "title": "Hyperandrogenism as a factor of reproductive losses",
  "publication_year": 2013, 
  "publication_date": "2013-03-27",
  "ids": {
    "openalex": "https://openalex.org/W2777209504",
    "doi": "https://doi.org/10.24026/1818-1384.1(42).2013.77470",
    "mag": 2777209504
  },
  "type": "journal-article",
  "counts_by_year": [
    {
      "year": 2019,
      "cited_by_count": 1
    }
  ],
  "cited_by_api_url": "https://api.openalex.org/works?filter=cites:W2777209504",
  "updated_date": "2021-11-03",
  "created_date": "2018-01-05",
  "abstract_inverted_index": {}
}
```

I tried the below two commands and neither of them worked: \

1. `gzcat -c sample.gz | jq -rc '[.doi,.title, .publication_year, .publication_date, .type] | select(.type |contains("dissertation")) | @csv'>target.csv`
2. `gzcat -c sample.gz | jq -rc '[.doi,.title, .publication_year, .publication_date, .type] | select(.type=="dissertation") | @csv'>target.csv`

The output received for both of them is: 
`jq: error (at <stdin>:108753): Cannot index string with string "title"`

I tried all possibles ways to filter down my JSON-LD file but I am unable to succeed. Any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: Neither of the commands you provided produce the output you claim to have received for the input you have provided. Even with the fixes I provided. So your data is different than what you claim, so it's waste of time for us to even try answering your question.

Comment: @ikegami how can you even make that assumption? Please quote that you did not understand the question. My data is exactly like i pointed in the question.

Comment: Re "*how can you even make that assumption?*", It's not as assumption. It's easy to see the code you posted wouldn't generate those messages for that input, and it's easy to run them to see they don't.

Comment: oops, there was an accidental assumption. I meant to say "So your data or code is different than what you claim"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both your attempts, the `select` is incorrectly formulated (or in the wrong place, depending on your point of view).  This would work:

```
select(.type == "dissertation")
| [.doi,.title, .publication_year, .publication_date, .type]
| @csv
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! How do I alias a field name? Like - 
```[.doi,.title, .publication_year as P_ YEAR, .publication_date, .type] | @csv``` ???

Comment: Re "*How do I alias a field name*", Arrays don't have field names. You're probably asking how to output a header row. The code would look something like `( [ "...", ... ], ... ) | @csv`